# Delete several files older than x days without compromising overall application performance

Tags: c#, windows

I have a Windows application, where I want run a thread that deletes files older than X days, N files at a time.

So I'm using `var files = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` in the first place to load all files info into an array.

Then I perform my Linq over the array, like this:

```
var result = files.Where(f => f.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)).OrderBy(f.CreationDate).Take(200);
```

Then I iterate over this result and delete one by one.

I was able to test this over 20000 records without any problem, but now I found out that this may run on a machine where there are more than 250000 records to delete.

So the question is, is this a good way to clean these files? Should I expect surprises such as memory or CPU high consumption? Or should I do this in another way?

Comment: _250000 records_! I'd not use Linq at all for this. Basic `for` loop and a single `if` statement will perform better. Do a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetFiles` method will create an in-memory array with all `FileInfo` objects, depending on the available memory this may be a limiting factor. An alternative would be to stream the `FileInfo` objects instead, this way it doesn't have to store all items in memory.

Quote from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-5.0):

> When you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of FileInfo objects to be returned before you can access the array.  Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

The paths can be streamed by using the `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` method that returns an `IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>` instead of a `System.IO.FileInfo[]`:

Example:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ExampleDir");
var filesToDelete = directory.EnumerateFiles()
                    .Where(f => f.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2));

foreach (var file in filesToDelete)
{
  Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```

Source: [Microsoft DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Hi, thanks this is a good tip. Is there any Way of knowing information about the file? I only want to delete files older than X time. I would have to create a file info for each file on the enumerable right? Btw another doubt. Does any one of these solutions lock the directory blocking it from writing other files?

Comment: to estimate the size of the array with strings you could measure it for 20k files and multiply it by 10, this will give a rough estimation of the size. But I think the `EnumerateFiles` option is better for scalability.

Comment: I think you should use the `EnumerateFiles` on `DirectoryInfo` instead of Directory to meet the OPs needs

Comment: True, good one! I have updated the answer.

Comment: That seems good as well, and how about your initial suggestion of Directory.EnumerateFiles and then for each file, use File.GetLastWriteTime? Or DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles should be enough?

Comment: Using `File.GetLastWriteTime` with the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and `File.GetLastWriteTime` would be a bit more efficient I think. It doesn't have to build an entire `FileInfo` object for each file. I think `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` won't cause any memory issues though because it only creates a single `FileInfo` at a time because it enumerates the results one for one

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect that memory or CPU will be the problem here. The disk IO will be the expensive part.

The memory used by the `FileInfo` objects depends greatly on the average length of the full path and filename.

Using 80 characters average path length as an estimate you could expect 250,000 `FileInfo` objects to take up roughly 70MB of memory.

The CPU cycles iterating through the list will be negligible.

Reading all the files to build the `FileInfo` objects will hit the disk pretty hard. You could notice the system slow down a bit while it is gathering all the disk info. I suppose you could mitigate that by putting this operation on a low priority background thread.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, in fact this is a low priority thread already (BelowNormal). I found out that instead of creating a FileInfo for each file, I can just check File.GetLastWriteTime which seams lighter

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var filesToDelete = Directory.EnumerateFiles("DirectoryPath")
                                        .Select(p => new {Name = p, LastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(p)})
                                        .Where(f => f.LastWriteTime <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-48))
                                        .Take(100);
```

Comment: Get top 100 files where its last write time is older than 48h, without any directory info or file info

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question with **windows**, you could also reduce the I/O priority of the thread by using some native methods:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class begins background processing mode on the current thread end ends it in <see cref="Dispose()"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// using (new BackgroundIOThreadContext())
/// {
///     // do background IO processing...
/// }
/// </code>
/// </example>
internal sealed class BackgroundIOThreadContext : IDisposable
{
    #region native
    private const int THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN = 0x00010000;

    private const int THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END = 0x00020000;

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a pseudo handle for the calling thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A pseudo handle for the current thread. The pseudo handle need not be closed when it is no longer needed.</returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

    /// <summary>
    /// See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthread for details and sample.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetThreadPriority(IntPtr handle, int priority);

    #endregion

    private readonly bool prioChanged;
    private readonly IntPtr threadHandle;
    private bool disposed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the class and begins background processing on the current thread.
    /// </summary>
    public BackgroundIOThreadContext()
    {
        threadHandle = GetCurrentThread();
        // If you are interested in return codes, use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(). In this scenario ignored.
        prioChanged = SetThreadPriority(threadHandle, THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);
    }

    ~BackgroundIOThreadContext()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ends background processing mode on the current thread.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool _)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;
        if (prioChanged)
            SetThreadPriority(threadHandle, THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END);
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Then start a background thread to enumerate/delete the files with lowest I/O (and optionally reduced CPU) priority:

```
public void StartDeleteOldFiles() => new Thread(DeleteOldFiles)
{
    IsBackground = true,
    //Lower CPU usage if you want. Bottleneck will be certainly IO, not CPU.
    //Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest
}.Start();

private void DeleteOldFiles()
{
    int total = 0;
    int deleted = 0;
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
    using (new BackgroundIOThreadContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in new DirectoryInfo(workingDir).EnumerateFiles())
        {
            total++;
            if (item.LastWriteTime < date)
            {
                item.Delete();
                deleted++;
            }
        }
    }
    Debug.Print($"Deleted {deleted} of {total} files.");
}
```

Reducing the priority of a thread with **Thread.Priority** does not lower the I/O priority. Using the **[SetThreadPriority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority)** API with **THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN** does.
You can check this with [Process Explorer](https://live.sysinternals.com/):

[image: Thread I/O priority]

Check it with and without using the API.